# adding spaces between <li> objects that is set as inline

Tags: html

I have a bunch of `<li></li>` tag:

```
 "<li><a href=\"" ><img id= src=\"a.png\" /></a></li>"
        "<li>         </li>"
       "<li><a href=\"" ><img id= src=\"b.png\" /></a></li>"
        "<li>          </li>"
      "<li><a href=\"" ><img id= src=\"c.png\" /></a></li>"
        "<li>           </li>"
```

with the following settings `ul li { display: inline; }`
so they are in one line and I want to put some spacing between those `<li>`, how can I do so? I tried by putting an empty `<li></li>` but I can't seem to adjust the spacing width.

Comment: yep use margins or padding, try adding "padding: 0 4px 0 4px;" to your style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `inline`, they'll still take widths and heights.